# how to Create Query on Lead to find All lead with Country 'India'

Tags: soql

SELECT Name, phone, email, company, country.india FROM lead

I am using this query to find all lead with country 'India' But its not working.

Comment: That is not valid SOQL syntax. Have you had a chance to complete the [introductory Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_database/units/apex_database_soql) that explains how to construct SOQL queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOQL queries that need to be filtered are done so using a WHERE clause. As mentioned above, Salesforce Trailhead has plenty of material to educate yourself on that but currently what you're looking for is:

```
SELECT Name, phone, email, company, country FROM lead where country = 'India'
```